# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError depending on Pyramid webapp serving method?

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, pyramid

This error in thrown only on production Apache2 server, and not at all when using pserve method to test the project locally :

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <My_Table at 0x7fc82076d2d0> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'my_table_relationship' cannot proceed
```

Crashing code in template is:

```
<tal:x repeat="oMot_cn oMot_mcnii_cni.r_mcnii_cp.r_newphonets">
```

This kind of chained relationships pattern had been working well so far, I am just trying to load the whole query object at launching time of the Pyramid app, instead of loading a new one each time a request is handled by the view/controller... 
It keeps crashing on production while it does not crash on pserve dev testing, so it's hard to debug.

Whole traceback on production server:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=15170): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/MyProject/myproject.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/chameleon/template.py", line 170, in render
     self._render(stream, econtext, rcontext)
   File "tp_lesson_T_ex_mots_from_audio_765c6cd23ec517b3893410ce969cf2d9.py", line 584, in render
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/chameleon/py26.py", line 5, in lookup_attr
     return getattr(obj, key)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 233, in __get__
     return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 579, in get
     value = self.callable_(state, passive)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 479, in _load_for_state
     (orm_util.state_str(state), self.key)
 sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Caract_phonet at 0x7fc82076d2d0> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'r_newphonets' cannot proceed

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/fanstatic/publisher.py", line 219, in __call__
     return self.app(environ, start_response)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/fanstatic/injector.py", line 64, in __call__
     response = request.get_response(self.app)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 1296, in send
     application, catch_exc_info=False)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 1260, in call_application
     app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 251, in __call__
     response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 227, in invoke_subrequest
     response = handle_request(request)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
     response = handler(request)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py3.2.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 82, in tm_tween
     reraise(*exc_info)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py3.2.egg/pyramid_tm/compat.py", line 13, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py3.2.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 63, in tm_tween
     response = handler(request)
   File "/var/local/env_py3/env_py3_2an/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 161, in handle_request
     response = view_callable(context, request)
```

Is there any missing PasteDeploy configuration to get it crashing the same way it does once it's pushed to production server ?

Comment: Please include a *minimal* example that produces the error, and relevant configuration. Full tracebacks instead of just the exception's string repr usually help as well.

Comment: Deep down I'd suspect this has something to do with how mod_wsgi handles workers using both [processes and threads](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html) because you're only seeing it in Apache, but it's hard to say. Usually one uses a scoped session in Pyramid, and since that's tied to a thread, it'd hint at that direction as well.

Comment: Updated post with tracebacks, and local config is : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 
+ Pyramid running in Python 3.4.6-based Virtualenv (Python 3.4.6 compiled from sources, after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 broke my previous python 3.4 virtualenv...)
Prod config is Pyramid running Python 3.2.3-based Virtualenv. 
Both virutalenvs run SqlAlchemy 0.9.4, and execute same code exactly.

Comment: Yes, using scoped session too.

Comment: Please include the view code as well, just in case.

Comment: What version of Pyramid? It [dropped support for Python 3.2](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/changes.html#id16) in Pyramid 1.7a1. Pyramid 1.9 was released yesterday and supports Python 2.7 and 3.4+. I strongly recommend using the same version of Python on both local and production environments. To do so, VMs or pyenv are possible options.

Comment: Ah just noticed what you had added. The preloading at application startup is the root of your problem, the rest just symptoms, I'd say. It'd be interesting to see the relevant parts of your app at this point.

Comment: You've probably either explicitly, or Pyramid has implicitly closed the session used at app startup to preload the data, and so it has been detached. Since the instance is detached from a session, it cannot lazy load relationship attributes.